# Set up a new PC with Windows 10 - More efficient/quick with cmd or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, automation

Sometimes i have to set-up a few new pc's with `windows 10 professional x64`.
**The system is already installed.**

When i turn on the PC i get to the first-time-login screen and have to set various options
like **region** or if i want to send **full-detail-reports to microsoft**, just for example.

Is it possible to save an already set-up profile and use it for all the machines?

i noticed that i can use cmd in the set-up-process with the shortcut `Shift+F11`
i also have an `Win-PE Image` available.

**---------What i have already tried:---------**

i already tried to use `Shift+F11` on first-time-logon-screen and typed following commands:

```
net user myuser pw /add
net localgroup adminstrators myuser /add
shutdown /l
```

the profile is created but i still have to finish the logon-process of the default-first-time-login-user.

`net user` is also not effecient because i have to make another first-time-login-wizard and make the same various options as mentioned above for the default-User.

Comment: "Is it possible to save an already set-up profile and use it for all the machines?" - Create your own partition image, which is already configured, and apply it to the partition using the appropriate tools.  You can also automate the installation of Windows using the appropriate XML file.  Is there a specific step you are stuck on?

Comment: Install Win10 > at OOBE Screen hold ALT+SHIFT+F5 to go into Audit mode > Customize your Windows installation > run sysprep / shutdown > power on > boot into clonezilla > save image > apply that image to any machine you want.

Comment: thanks very much sir @Mastaxx  thanks Audit mode and the sysprep is what i needed 
Why do you recommend `Clonezilla` and not `Macrium`, is there some key-difference?
What about the `windows-serial-number` if i apply the preconfigured image to another device?

Comment: I use clonezilla only because it's what we've had here for a long time and we haven't moved on from it yet. We'll soon be moving onto a more sophisticated re-imaging solution that allows us to do it remotely (like fog server). Running sysprep will generalize the image for use on any machine. So when your re-imaged machines fire up for the "first time" the operating system will query the BIOS chip for its unique product key and automatically apply it. This guide is especially useful for learning how to create your first basic image without over complicating it...

Comment: ... you can ignore the parts that cover fog server setup... unless it interests you

Comment: https://www.ceos3c.com/sysadmin/create-generalized-windows-10-image-deploy-fog-server/

Comment: It also helps a lot to save out an image of your progress while in audit mode.. so you can easily go back to rebuilding a new image as time goes on and your user software/settings requirements evolve.

Comment: With regards to the questions that are answered at the OOBE screen, including region, data collection etc.. this is handled also while in audit mode with the Windows System Image Manager. You need to create your own custom answer file that is set to answer those questions for you, and you can also set it so that the OOBE process is skipped.. You can also set for a custom admin user to be created on first startup as well. It's all there provided by microsoft... and there is a wealth of info out there on all the components within Image Manager so you can create the perfect image.

Comment: thank you very much @Mastaxx 
i will try everything out - i really appreciate your input!